# Unable to move shell schript to init.d, is in read only file-system on an embedded linux

Tags: shell-script, sysvinit, readonly

When I do

```
cp run-rfid-script.sh /init.d
```

I get this error message

```
cp: can't create '/init.d': Read-only file system
```

How can I overcome this problem?

---

## Other info on what I am doing

I have a shell script to run my application which is like below one,

```
#!/bin/bash
/cust/start
exit 0
~
```

The application is named as "start" under cust folder. If I run the `/cust/start`, I am able to successfully run the application without any problem,

```
root@SpeedwayR-12-77-27:/# /cust/start
Tag report
-----------------------------------
Antenna ID : 1
EPC : D0D0-0000-0000-0000-0001-AB48
Timestamp : 1588049457805341
Peak RSSI : -59
FastID : E2003412017FFE00045DE483
TID : E2003412
User memory (Word 0) : 0000
```

Now, I want to run the same application i.e. Start bash script, in `cust` folder, when the system gets booted. I have used the bash script which is given above and when I am trying to place the bash script in init.d folder, it says `Read only file system`.

**Suggestions by binarysta**

```
root@SpeedwayR-12-77-27:/etc# awk '$2=="/" {print $0}' /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / jffs2 ro,relatime 0 0
root@SpeedwayR-12-77-27:/etc# awk '$2=="/" {print $0}' /etc/fstab  
root@SpeedwayR-12-77-27:/etc# ls -l init.d                         
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           285 Nov 19 23:44 S50avahi-daemon*
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           423 Nov 19 23:44 S60lldpd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          2793 Nov 19 23:44 networking*
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          5097 Nov 19 23:44 rcS*
root@SpeedwayR-12-77-27:/etc#
```

Comment: the `init.d` directory should be in `/etc/init.d/` as far as I know. Anyway seems root filesystem is read-only so please update the question with output of these commands. `awk '$2=="/" {print $0}' /proc/mounts` and `awk '$2=="/" {print $0}' /etc/fstab` and `ls -l /init.d`.

Comment: The question needs to tell people what operating system this embedded system is running.  Linux is not an operating system, merely the kernel of one.  Identifying the operating system will identify whether what you are attempting is even meaningful.

Comment: An embedded system might be designed to run with the root filesystem read-only all the time. In that case, the root filesystem type might be `squashfs`: that does not support writing at all. If your situation is like that, the only way would be to extract the filesystem image to some other computer, make modifications there, build a new squashfs image file, and somehow replace the current root filesystem image on the embedded system with the new file.

Comment: @binarysta, updated the output of the given commands